# How to deploy the app to AWS

Tags: cordova, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, mean-stack

This is a very beginner level question. I want some directions. I've created a `MEAN` based app. It works locally `(localhost)`. the structure is :

[image]

`app.js` is the node server. `models` has the mongo schemas. `public` has index.html, css folder and js folder. I'm using `angularjs`. The app is going to upload images so I'll use the AWS S3 storage. Also using mongo for db.

My questions:

1. How do I pack this with `Phonegap` to create it a hybrid app?
2. Should I host on EC2 or Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: Use Beanstalk for server environment. It will simplify the deployment providing you with gui options for autoscaling and loadbalancing configuration. For Phonegap use their Cloud Build service which is more convenient in the long run when you support multiple mobile platforms

Comment: Thanks. I can use the normal code for `node.js` right? Do I need to code `node.js` anything different to host it on `Beanstalk`?

Comment: Normal code would work. Hope your app starts with 'npm start' or 'node .'  If you plan to store any files in the instance better to move them to S3 or AWS Elastic File System

Answer (score 0):

For Phonegap use their Cloud Build service which is more convenient in the long run when you support multiple mobile platforms.

Use Beanstalk for server environment. It will simplify the deployment providing you with gui options for autoscaling and loadbalancing configuration and greatly simplify deployment and rollbacks